# Health package showing wrong steps data in iOS in flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-dependencies, healthkit

Using Health [Package](https://pub.dev/packages/health) in flutter it is showing wrong data in iOS, but when we use it in android where google fit comes in it is showing perfect steps data. Does anyone have a solution to that? Any leads would be appreciated.